# Java and javascript generates different output for Base64 Hmac SHA256

Tags: javascript, java, sha256, hmac

When I tried to create similar function in Java and javascript which outputs a Base64 string of a Hmac SHA 256 encryption, the output given is not the same.

Javascript

```
var dataToSign = "message";
var secret = "secret";
function generateAuthHeader(dataToSign){
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dataToSign,secret);
    return hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

which outputs

```
+eZuF5tnR65UEI+C+K3os8Jddv0wr95sOVgixTAZYWk=
```

Java

```
String key="secret"; 
String dataToSign = "message"; 
Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(dataToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

which outputs

```
i19IcCmVwVmMVz2x4hhmqbgl1KeU0WnXBgoDYFeWNgs=
```

is there errors in my code?

Comment: Perhaps the UTF-8 makes the difference?

Comment: tried removing it, no changes to the output

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. On my machine, both codes produce the result `i19IcCmVwVmMVz2x4hhmqbgl1KeU0WnXBgoDYFeWNgs=`, which is actually correct (this can easily be verified with e.g. https://cryptii.com/pipes/hmac)

Comment: The other output can be reproduced using an empty string: `console.log(generateAuthHeader(""));`

Comment: turns out I did not pass any arguments when I called `generateAuthHeader()`, hence `dataToSign` is an empty string. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of `hash` in the JavaScript version and what's the value of `sha256_HMAC.doFinal(dataToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))` in the Java version?

Also, can you please try getting the Base64 repr in JavaScript:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

instead of `hash.toString` ?

Also UTF-8 shouldn't make a difference in the Java version, but I'd try to remove those and simply do `getBytes()` everywhere.

Comment: the hash value from the javascript is `f9e66e179b6747ae54108f82f8ade8b3c25d76fd30afde6c395822c530196169`
while the value of `sha256_HMAC.doFinal(dataToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))` in Java is in byte format `[B@27c170f0`

Comment: the Base64 repr in Javascript has the same output as the `hash.toString` method. Tried removing `UTF-8` from `getBytes()`, no changes in the output

Comment: This might help: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/